# Elastic Beanstalk listening for tcp connections

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have nodejs app which is listening for http connections on port 3000 and also listening for tcp connections on port 5001 using nodejs' net library.

I am hosting the app using aws elastic beanstalk and it's classic load balancer.

My CLB listeners:

[image: CLB listeners]

My Elastic Beanstalk load balancer listeners:

[image: eb lb listeners]

Also port 5001 is enabled in ec2 instance and load balancer security groups.

When trying to send tcp packet to load balancer's dns name it goes through, but never reaches the ec2 instance. Is there something else I have to configure for this to be possible?

Comment: Check the security groups for the load balancer and the EC2 instance to make sure port 5001 is open.

Comment: @MarkB I have triple checked and the ports are open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had net.listen host set to localhost instead of 0.0.0.0